# Python: PIP (PyPI) Exception error ( I am confused)

Tags: python, exception, pip, pygame, pypi

I am confused. I found a game made in Python on GitHub and wanted to try it out, so I downloaded the files. I then installed Python, in this case, x86-32 3.8.3 windows. Note: I **didn't use the system-wide installation option** and instead went with the *single-user install mode* as I didn't need an elevation. I set it up to install a full installation and it worked. **BUT** when I went to run the game, it said I didn't have PyGame installed. I thought,

> No biggie, guess I'll install PyGame.

So, I went to cmd, and searched for PyGame on pip. This is what it outputted:

```
C:\Users\[username]>pip search pygame
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 48, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 65, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1012, in request
    return self.parse_response(response.raw)
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1341, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 655, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32500: "RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API has been temporarily disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.">
```

Now, I'm no expert, but I know something's wrong. What does this mean? How do I fix it? I don't know! And that's the thing, I don't know how this happened, considering there were no errors during the Python installation, at least when I checked the log file.

*I have never been **so** confused in all 10 years I've been programming for. So, help me out on this one.*

Answer (score 0):

`pip search` has been removed because PyPI could not sustain the amount of searches that it was asked to handle due to denial of service attacks. As  discussed in [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9312#issuecomment-748187722) issue,
nothing seems to be wrong with your installation it is just that the `pip search` command has been removed.